# Ms-Access 2016 button that creates a multiple of buttons on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have my Main form that I have created a button on, when I click this button I want it to open another form and create a multiple button with names on that I pull from a table.
I have started some VBA for the button already but I'm stuck on getting it to create the buttons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I hope someone in the community can guide me in the right direction as I'm new to this area.
Please see details below.

Main form name HomePage_frm: VBA for the button on this form is below.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Select * " & _
"FROM Users_tbl " & _
"WHERE Authority = 'Supervisor'"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

Dim strText As String

Do While Not rs.EOF

strText = rs.Fields("Employee_Name")

'Make Buttons here

rs.MoveNext

Loop

End Sub
```

I have looked all over and found a few ideas but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Review https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221167(v=office.11).aspx. Why do you want multiple buttons that dynamically display employee names? Why make life difficult? Why not just a combobox or listbox?

Answer (score 1):

1- In Access VBA You can't dynamically create controls on forms not in design mode. you can do it in design mode then load the form.

2- It can be done in easier way by design a form with default view as **"Continuous Forms"** and link it to the table of names (or query on the table) and set button caption in Detail **"Paint"** event.

Attached Picture  "Table.jpg" the table.
[image: Table]

Attached Picture  "Form.jpg" the form with button **"command0"**.
[image: Form]

Form running view and d button clicked
[image]

Following is the form code

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Command0_Click()
   If Not IsNull(Me!CliName) Then
       MsgBox Me!CliName
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Detail_Paint()
   If Not IsNull(Me!CliName) Then
       Command0.Caption = Me!CliName
   Else
       Command0.Caption = ""
   End If
End Sub
```

I hope it is clear and helpful